# Google Sheets on Android: frozen column can't be resized?

Tags: google-sheets

I wished to freeze the first 2 columns in Google Sheets on Android:

[image]

However, after freezing, these frozen columns will get a fixed width, and I can't change it (although I have a scrollbar).

[image]

I wish to expand the frozen columns so that I can see all of them. Is it somehow possible to overcome this?